# How to queue email deliveries using rake tasks in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rake, rails-activejob

I'm trying to **schedule email deliveries** by using whenever and a rake task

```
every 1.month, at: 'start of the month at 4am' do
  rake "reports:deliver_reports"
end
```

Inside my **rake task**, I use a class to **queue all email deliveries**:

```
# reports.rake
namespace :reports do
  # rake reports:deliver_reports
  desc "Send reports to users"
  task deliver_reports: :environment do 
    QueueReportsService.call
  end
end
```

And inside that class, **I queue each email delivery.**

```
class QueueReportsService
  def self.call
    users = User.all
    users.each { |user| ReportMailer.report(user).deliver_later }
  end
end
```

Based on a [question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48364051/rails-5-actionmailers-deliver-later-never-delivers-in-production) previously posted on SO I understand that:

> Rails itself only provides an in-process queuing system, which only keeps the jobs in **RAM**.

And that:

> ... Using the asynchronous queue from a Rake task (... to send an email using .deliver_later) **will generally not work** because Rake will likely end, **causing the in-process thread pool to be deleted** ...

I know that using `deliver` instead of `deliver_later` will send the emails.

```
class QueueReportsService
  def self.call
    users = User.all
    users.each { |user| ReportMailer.report(user).deliver }
  end
end
```

However, **if for some reason the rake task is interrupted, every subsequent email will not be sent.** **I'd like to prevent this** from happening **by scheduling a separate job for each user email** that, if something goes wrong, will fail in isolation.

Comment: Keep in mind ActiveJob is more of a standard interface than an implementation per-se. There's [numerous ActiveJob back-ends](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#backends) you can use that have different features.

Comment: @tadman I understand that ActiveJob is an interface, but will one of these backend implementations you shared allow the `deliver_later` method to work as intended, or will the code need to be further modified?

Comment: @AlvaroAlday if you stick to sidekiq or resque (maybe there are others), it will work as expected. It's similar to active record database adapters in that your code doesn't need to be modified to work across the technologies that Rails supports via adapters.

Comment: @MarkMerritt I got into our codebase and learned that we're currently using delayed _job as our backend. So why is delayed_job not taking care of the queue generated by the rake task? Does DelayedJob need further configuration?